# Whenever I start my node server and type localhost:3000 it is giving me an error: TypeError: fd must be a file descriptor

Tags: node.js

I am new beginner in angular. I am using Visual Studio code tool and I am trying to create a server using nodejs 
I am trying to load my index.html file when a user sends requests to the server my js code is:

```
var http=require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req,res){
  fs.read("./public/index.html","UTF-8", function(err,html){

    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
  } );
}).listen(3000);

TypeError: fd must be a file descriptor
at Object.fs.read (fs.js:686:11)
at Server.<anonymous> (E:\NodejsWork\server.js:7:7)
at Server.emit (events.js:180:13)
at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:642:12)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:117:17)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fs.read method needs a file descriptor as a param, not a file path.
([fs.read documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback))

What you are probably looking for is fs.readFile(path[, options], callback) ([fs.readFile documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback))